# Configuring ssl/tls on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I'm stuck with a problem with configuring ssl/tls on tomcat. The problem is as follows:
I import my certificate using keytool command
but when configuring server.xml, I get two issues:
if I specify keyAlias attribute as:

```
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200" keyAlias="tomcat"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/ssl/mykeystorefile.keystore" keystorePass="****"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I get the exception:

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: L''initialisation du gestionnaire de protocole a échoué
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Le nom alias [tomcat] n'identifie pas une entrée de clef
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1086)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:268)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Le nom alias [tomcat] n'identifie pas une entrée de clef
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:229)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114)
    ... 20 more

and when not specifying the attribute I get same exception with null instead of tomcat entry.
Thanks for your help,

Comment: Please post the *entire* stack trace, even if it's hundreds of lines long. What you have already posted doesn't include enough information.

Comment: Use keytool -list to show the keystore content. Maybe you missed one step when generating the private key, and importing its certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I indeed missed including the private key in jks file.
I followed that tutorial, and it worked:
https://www.wowza.com/docs/How-to-request-an-SSL-certificate-from-a-certificate-authority